# adding keys and values to query string

Tags: c#, .net, get, query-string

I am trying to do :

```
foreach (JProperty o in obj.Properties())
{
   string ke = o.Name.ToString();
   string va = o.Value.ToString();
   HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add(ke,va);
}
```

but it gives me the error `"collection is read-only"`

HOW can I add values to querystring then ?

Thanks

Comment: It shows "read-only", means you can't *add*. You have to create a new one and assign the query from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Request.QueryString is the url you recieve from the server. You cant change it. What you can do is execute a response redirect with the query string like so:

```
string qs = "?";
foreach (JProperty o in obj.Properties())
{
   qs += o.Name.ToString();
   qs += "=" + o.Value.ToString() + "&";
}
Response.Redirect("url/index" + qs);
```

Comment: so in fact with redirect it will recall the handler?

Comment: Not recall but call. It will create/add a querystring and call a new handler.

Comment: in my solution I can not call again. so in this case there is no way to add values to QueryString , am I right?

Comment: Yes, cant change it unless you call again. If you REALLY REALLY insist on changing the querystring, something that is BAD PRACTICE then check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450505/override-request-querystring which gives you an option to change it BEFORE you recieve it